# Unable to start new settings after creating Navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, settings, preferenceactivity

I have been working on navigation drawer for the last two days. I need to add a settings activity. So, When I add a settings activity, The wizard fails to respond while clicking finish or cancel button.

Thanks in advance.

screenshot is attached below.

[When I try to add a settings activity, The android studio is struck with this window. Neither the buttons function nor the studio when trying to close. The buttons highlights though.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewd3X.png)

Comment: try restarting android studio

Comment: @CodedPhoenix Did that !! But not use... I also tried creating settings activity in black activity. It worked. But, not in navigation drawer one !

Comment: Does android studio give `IllegalStateException` error whenever you try that.